# Как заставить Dolphin Service Menu максимально сжимать в tar.lzma?

Tags: linux, kde

То ли ark, то ли xz по умолчанию жмет где-то на -6. Не смог найти как это изменить.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin
MimeType=all/all;
Icon=ark
Actions=compressHereAsTarLzma;

[Desktop Action compressHereAsTarLzma]
Name=Compress here as TAR.LZMA
Icon=ark
Exec=ark --changetofirstpath --add --autofilename tar.lzma %F
```

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/28977/136975 ?

Comment: @donRumata Приблизительно оно. Но, пока не понимаю как прикрутить это вместо ark. Похоже, придется проштудировать man xz и подробно изучить как работают .desktop файлы.

Comment: Ты не можешь воткнуть переменную окружения в .desktop файл?